# Lorentz group in 1+1 dimension

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, lorentz-symmetry

Consider the Minkowski 2D metric $\eta = \text{diag}(-1, 1)$. The Lorentz group is the set of matrices such that, for a transformation $\Lambda$, we get

$$\eta = \Lambda^T \eta \Lambda$$

This means

\begin{eqnarray}
\Lambda^\dagger \eta \Lambda &=& \begin{pmatrix}
a & c \\
b & d
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=& \begin{pmatrix}
c^2 - a^2 & cd - ab \\
cd - ab & d^2 - b^2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}

So that we get the equalities

\begin{eqnarray}
cd &=& ab\\
c^2 &=& a^2 - 1\\
d^2 &=& 1 + b^2
\end{eqnarray}

We can replace $c$ with, let's say at random, $\sinh(u)$, as it is a bijection on $\mathbb{R}$, so that

\begin{eqnarray}
\sinh^2(u) + 1 &=& a^2
\end{eqnarray}

meaning that $a = \pm \cosh(u)$. Similarly with $b = \sinh(v)$, we get

$$d^2 = 1 + \sinh^2(v)$$

so $d = \pm \cosh(v)$. Now there are four possible cases to treat $cd = ab$, depending on the signs of $a$ and $d$ : $++$, $+-$, $-+$ and $--$.

For $++$ :

\begin{eqnarray}
cd - ab &=& \sinh(u) \cosh(v) - \cosh(u) \sinh(v)\\
&=& \sinh(u - v)
\end{eqnarray}

Meaning $u = v$, this is just the orthochronous oriented Lorentz transform,

\begin{eqnarray}
\Lambda = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cosh(u) & \sinh(u) \\
\sinh(u) & \cosh(u)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}

For $+-$ :

\begin{eqnarray}
cd - ab &=& -(\sinh(u) \cosh(v) + \cosh(u) \sinh(v))\\
&=& -\sinh(u + v)
\end{eqnarray}

Meaning that $u = -v$. From the parity properties of hyperbolic functions, that is

\begin{eqnarray}
\Lambda = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cosh(u) & -\sinh(u) \\
\sinh(u) & -\cosh(u)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}

For $-+$ :

\begin{eqnarray}
cd - ab &=& \sinh(u) \cosh(v) + \cosh(u) \sinh(v)\\
&=& \sinh(u + v)
\end{eqnarray}

Meaning that $u = -v$.

\begin{eqnarray}
\Lambda = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-\cosh(u) & -\sinh(u) \\
\sinh(u) & \cosh(u)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}

with similar proofs, the rest will be

\begin{eqnarray}
\Lambda = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-\cosh(u) & \sinh(u) \\
\sinh(u) & -\cosh(u)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}

Now the first matrix is entirely fine as it is the $SO^\uparrow(2)$ matrix, and the second one is a Lorentz transformation with parity reversal. But the rest doesn't seem to correspond to the usual matrices, which are the Lorentz transform composed with parity and time reversal :

\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{pmatrix}
\cosh(u) & \sinh(u) \\
\sinh(u) & \cosh(u)
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
-\cosh(u) & \sinh(u) \\
-\sinh(u) & \cosh(u)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{pmatrix}
\cosh(u) & \sinh(u) \\
\sinh(u) & \cosh(u)
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
\cosh(u) & -\sinh(u) \\
\sinh(u) & -\cosh(u)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{pmatrix}
\cosh(u) & \sinh(u) \\
\sinh(u) & \cosh(u)
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
-\cosh(u) & -\sinh(u) \\
-\sinh(u) & -\cosh(u)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}

where is the error here?

Comment: Maybe because the sign of $u$ is not determined, so that your third Lorentz matrix is in fact the same as the first of the last three matrices, with $u\rightarrow-u$. And similarly your fourth Lorentz matrix is just the last of the last three matrices.

Comment: True, flipping the signs of the last two would give back all the relevant matrices