# Meaning of 1+1 dimensions

Tags: spacetime, metric-tensor, definition, spacetime-dimensions

I came across the notion of 1+1 dimensions in a condensed matter context and, in particular, while studying bosonization, which relates to 1D quantum systems. Indeed, the Wikipedia article about it makes reference to 1+1 dimensions in the very first sentence, though the hyperlink redirects to the more general articles about dimensions. What is meant with $d+1$ dimensions? Why is in this case 1 or 2 less appropriate than 1+1?

Comment: 1 spatial + 1 temporal dimensions.

Comment: So by saying 1D we mean we are dealing with a time-independent theory?

Comment: @KarimChahine No. 1D could either mean 0+1 or 1+1. If the former, it means that the theory *only* depends on time. If the latter, it means that the theory depends on both time and one spatial dimension. So "1D" is ambiguous and should never be used. It could mean different things to different people. (But it almost universally never means time-independent. That would be a Euclidean 0+1 theory, which does exist but is rarely referred to as just a 1D theory. You need to give it its full name).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform was there a typo, should the Euclidean theory be 1+0?

Comment: @electronpusher Maybe he means zero space and one Euclidean time dimension.

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/264525/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/495971/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/604208/226902

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simplify a problem and perhaps gain some insight in how to solve it in its full form, physicists sometimes create a "toy universe" which is missing one or two spatial dimensions, and recast their problem in that toy universe. Sometimes the problem can be solved in that universe and sometimes that solution is of use.

Our universe is (3+1), for 3 dimensions of space and one of time. Toy universes could be (2+1), in which one dimension of space is omitted, or (1+1) in which two dimensions of space are omitted.

In addition, as d_b points out in his comment below, there are real-world systems in condensed matter physics which have *effectively* less than 3 spatial dimensions, and that these systems are not "toy universes" as described above.

Comment: There are also plenty of real world condensed systems that *effectively* have one, two, or zero spatial dimensions, in that the system size is much larger in some directions than others.

Comment: will edit to include. -NN